# When does a Cognito user's identity id of identity pool is created?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I've to perform few operations on a user's identity ID which is reflected into Identity Pool.

By observing from the Console, it seems identity ID is not created on a user signup, and during login of a user it is reflected into Identity pool.

Exactly when the identity id is created?

Comment: How do you design and implement your authentication? Identity ID will be generated once you succeed credential exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's created when the first [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) is called.